# Quotient of the free Poisson algebra

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra

Assume  is the free Poisson algebra on the set of generators $=\{_{1},_{2},…,_{}\}$. It is well-known that  is the polynomial algebra with infinitely many generators $y_{1}$, $y_{2}$, ... where $_{1}=_{1}$,…,$_{}=_{}$,$_{+1}=[_{1},_{2}]$,... is a basis of the free Lie algebra on  and [-,-] denotes the Lie bracket on this free Lie algebra.
What is the quotient of  by the Poisson ideal generated by the set $\{_{1},_{2},...,_{n}\}$?